# SQL injection in GraphQL

Tags: security, graphql, owasp, apollo-server, graphql-java

I am working with GraphQL(Apollo GraphQL), Currently, i am doing security testing of my endpoints using owasp security tool(**OWASP ZAP**).
I getting alerted like sql injection in endpoints(**SQL injection may be possible.**).How to resolve sql injection in GraphQL.Any suggestion please ,Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be helpful to specify the specific security tools and the alert message to better understand the context. Given graphql is a relatively new tech, it won't be surprising that current security tools do not understand it and the alert being a false positive. Especially so when we are sending a sql-like payload over the wire via post method, it do looks suspiciously like a sql injection attempt.

Comment: @IvanChoo Thank you for your reply, Updated question please check it.

Comment: Do you even use SQL? Do you really use unsanitized user input to create SQL queries? There's nothing in neither Apollo nor GraphQL that even knows about SQL, so the warning is either bogus or you're doing something bad. And you gave no info on what your application does.